# Getting errors while I'm connecting to Hbase from Spark using Amazon EMR?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to connect Hbase tables from Spark using Amazon EMR. I'm using the below versions of the drivers.

Hbase : 1.1.2.2.3.4.0-3485
Phoenix driver : 4.2.0.2.2.0.0-2041

When i'm running my fat jar on EMR getting below errors. I tried to resolve but got struck.

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString cannot access its superclass com.google.protobuf.LiteralByteString
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1613)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:924)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.getTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1168)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.updateCache(MetaDataClient.java:349)
org.apache.phoenix.compile.FromCompiler$SingleTableColumnResolver.<init>(FromCompiler.java:215)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.FromCompiler.getResolverForQuery(FromCompiler.java:159)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:304)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:294)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:215)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:211)
        at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:210)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixPreparedStatement.java:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
        at spid_part1$.main(spid_part1.scala:71)
        at spid_part1.main(spid_part1.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString cannot access its superclass com.google.protobuf.LiteralByteString
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$5.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1176)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$5.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$16.call(HTable.java:1646)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help on this, Thanks

Comment: were you able to fix this ? im getting the same issue.

Comment: No I haven't fixed this issue yet, still looking for a solution.

Comment: fat jars doesnt help u fix version conflicts in spark since your jar basically runs after the spark libs are loaded into the jvm so the versions will always conflict. if you have version issues then your basically fucked unless the dependent lib is small enough and doesnt conflict on its own 3rd party dependecies. then, just shade that lib and it shouldnt conflict anymore.